# Is it possible to upload to Amazon S3 with part less then 5 MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to upload to Amazon s3 with part less then 5 MB?

I'm now using Android client but I think it doesn't matter.

I'm trying to upload file to Amazon S3 with Android by parts.

And I want these parts be less the 5MB (1MB for example) but I can't.

EDIT:

```
// Step 1: Initialize.
                InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new
                        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
                InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

                File file = new File(filePath);
                long contentLength = file.length();
                long partSize = 15 * 1024 * 1024; // Set part size to ~ 1 MB.

                try {
                    // Step 2: Upload parts.
                    long filePosition = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
                        // Last part can be less than 5 MB. Adjust part size.
                        partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));

                        // Create request to upload a part.

                        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                                .withBucketName(existingBucketName).withKey(keyName)
                                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(i)
                                .withFileOffset(filePosition)
                                .withFile(file)
                                .withPartSize(partSize);
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you told us, what problem you are trying to solve and what you tried so far.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Added expanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly to [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html) "each part must be at least 5 MB in size, except the last part"